# MOD_WSGI cannot locate Oracle instantclient library

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, cx-oracle

I have a flask app running on `Apache server` using `mod_wsgi`. Everything works fine until I try to access the database using cx_Oracle. At that moment I get the following error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help`.

I have added the client library path to the os environment variables.
It works well if I start the application from Pycharm IDE.

I have even added the following line in my `.wsgi` file.

```
sys.path.append('D:\FlaskDev\instantclient_11_2')
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If your python is 64Bits you must to use an 64 instant client too.
Try to follow [this](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#id3) instructions.